# Oracle 11gR1 - case insenstive columns

Tags: oracle11g

Oracle 11gR1

Is there a way to set an Oracle instance to treat all columns as uppercase i.e. make the Oracle instance case-insensitive when accessing a database that has case-sensitive column names?

Comment: Isn't Oracle case-insensitive by default?

Comment: The below will create two columns in a table named 'employee', one upper and one lower.  I want to prevent this from happening.                        create table employee (emp_name varchar2(20), "emp_name"     varchar2(20));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is, by default, case-insensitive.  You'd only have case-sensitive identifiers if the original developer intentionally created them that way.  If that's what was done, you'd have no choice but to use case-sensitive names when interacting with the database (one of the reasons that case-sensitive identifiers are discouraged).

You could, of course, write a bit of dynamic SQL that would alter any table or column names that were created in a case-sensitive manner to be case-insensitive.  But that would likely break any code that is currently written that assumes that the identifiers are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks.  That is the problem I am facing -- source system tables with lowercase and uppercase column names but, depending on the source system, the column names could be either lower- or upper-case.  There's no consistency from the source system side.